# c++. Smart pointer for a member object of a class whose instance itself is owned by a smart pointer. Necessary?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

```
class Foo
{
public:
    int fooInt;
};

class Bar
{
    Foo fooInBar;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::unique_ptr<Bar> myBar = std::make_unique<Bar>();
}
```

I am aware that `myBar` is protected against a memory leak pretty well by being owned by a smart pointer.

Is the Foo object `fooInBar` protected also just by the nature of it being inside `myBar`, or should the member variable `fooInBar` also be contained in a smart pointer? Like so:

```
class Bar:
fooInBar(make_unique<Foo>())
{
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> fooInBar;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Member objects, unless dynamically allocated memory, are *safe* from this point of view. So, no, you don't need to wrap it in a smart pointer.

Specifically `fooInBar`, being it a subobject of `Bar`, it will be destroyed automatically by the destructor of `Bar`. The same goes for `fooInt` in `Foo`.

And finally, unless you really need dynamic memory, you can also avoid the use of smart pointers in the first place:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Bar myBar;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to. Since `fooInBar` is a sub-object inside object of type `Bar`, it will be destroyed **as part of** the containing `Bar` object when the latter one is released by smart pointer.

If, however, `fooInBar` is allocated separately on the heap, you should release it first before the containing `Bar` object is destroyed. E.g. destroy it in the destructor of `Bar`.

```
class Bar
{
public:
    Bar()
    {
       // You can also use a smart pointer
       // to manage the life cycle of "fooInBar"
       Foo *fooInBar = new Foo;
       ..
    }
    ~Bar()
    {
       // "fooInBar" needs to be released here
    }
private:
    Foo *fooInBar;
};
```